# How to show that the kernel of this ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[i]\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is the principal ideal $(2+i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

In order to prove that $Z[i]/(2+i)\cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, I defined the homomorphism $\phi(a+bi)=(a-2b)\mod 5$. It is easy to show that $2+i\in\ker(\phi)$, but I'm unsure how to prove the reverse inclusion.

I have the following so far: Suppose $a+bi\mapsto 0$. Then $a-2b\equiv 0\mod 5$, so $5$ divides $a-2b$.

I'm wondering if I can use the fact that $2+i$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Going from where you left off, suppose that $a-2b = 5n$; then $a+bi = 2b+5n+bi$.  Now, why is this a multiple of $2+i$?

Comment: I got it now, thank you very much: I found that $(2+i)[b+n(2-i)]=2b+5n+bi$.

Answer (score 0):

Now show that the quotient has five elements (for example, by considering $\mathbb Z[i]$ as a free abelian group of rank two and the ideal $(2+i)$ as the subgroup generated by $(2,1)$ and $(-1,2)$, and doing row and column reduction i.e. Smith normal form). Any surjective or injective function between sets of the same cardinality is bijective.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, would you mind clarifying: is this answer intended to help me prove the isomorphism or is it related to showing that $\ker(\phi)\subset (2+i)$? (My confusion is mostly with the latter) Thanks for your answer regardless.

Comment: @FakeAnalyst56 You know that $\mathbb Z[i]/\ker\phi$ has five elements: the induced map is *onto* $\mathbb Z/5$ so this is an isomorphism. The inclusion you gave provides you with a map from $\mathbb Z[i]/\ker\phi \to \mathbb Z[i]/(2+i)$ which is *onto*. Check that this last quotient *also* has five elements to conlude this is an isomorphism, so $(2+i)=\ker\phi$.